# "Console lock display off time-out" not working

Tags: windows-8.1, lock

I followed the advice of numerous tutorials to enable the "Console lock display off time-out" setting in advanced power options, and I have changed my currently active plan to time out after 1 minute on the lock screen:

[image: Advanced power settings]

My problem is, it simply doesn't seem to work.  I press OK, then press WinKey+L to lock the display, yet the monitor doesn't turn off after one minute.  Is there some AD policy that could be overriding this, and if so, how do I check what that policy is set to?  Or why else might it not be working?  I even tried restarting the machine but to no avail; the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

> ⚠ If **Turn off display after** is set to **Never**, it will also prevent
> **Console lock display off timeout** from turning off the display.

From https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65592-change-lock-screen-display-off-timeout-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score -1):

Console lock timeout is intended to only lock the session, the same thing as pressing W-L. 
The screen sleep time is different.

Comment: No, the asker is correct.  _[Console lock display off timeout is the amount of minutes Windows will wait idle with no activity while on the lock screen when a user locks the computer before timing out and automatically turning off the display.](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65592-change-lock-screen-display-off-timeout-windows-10-a.html)_